# indirectly convex

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let g:$\mathbb{R^2}$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ be defined by g(x)=Max{$x_1$,$x_2$} at each x=($x_1$,$x_2$)$\in$ $\mathbb{R}$. Determine whether or not g is indirectly convex on $\mathbb{R^2}$.
definition:
let f:$\mathbb{R^n}$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ be a function. We say that f is indirectly convex if there exist F:$\mathbb{R^n}$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ and h:$\mathbb{R}$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$ such that F is convex, h is increasing with $f=h \circ F$.

Comment: Don't you mean $f=h\circ F$?

Comment: yes, that is exactly right.

Comment: And $g(x) = \max\{x_{1},x_{2}\}$ instead of $x_{i}$?

Comment: yes that is true too

Comment: Convexity seems to imply indirect convexity. So why not $F=g$ and $h(x)=x$?

Answer (score 1):

Convexity implies direct convexity, and $g$ is convex. So simply choosing $F=g$ and $h(x)=x$ will suffice.

EDIT: coffeemath makes a fair point: what if you don't know that $\max$ is convex; that is, what if you have to prove it? I omitted that because in my experience, $\max$ is one of the first functions you get to put in your "atomic convex function toolbox." But if you can't do that yet, his approach is simple: $\max\{a,b\}=\tfrac{1}{2}(a+b+|a-b|)$, which is the sum of a linear function $a+b$ and a convex function $|a-b|$, scaled by a positive constant. Hence it is convex.

Comment: Yes, and $g$ convex follows from $\max(a,b)=1/2(a+b+|a-b|).$ And +1

Comment: Good stuff. In my experience $\max$ is treated as one of the "basic" convex functions. But if it's not, coffeemath's expression is a great way to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect convex implies convex sub-level sets $V_a = \lbrace x | f(x) \leq a \rbrace$ and that higher level curves contain lower ones.  This could be the exact condition, and it is true for $g(x)$.